# How do pegasi move clouds in My Little Pony: Friendship in Magic?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

In the television series *My Little Pony: Friendship in Magic*, pegasus ponies are shown to have the ability to move clouds on several occasions and also demonstrate the ability to incite rain, as seen in the episode ["Look Before You Sleep"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BXifdep6WtI). I'm aware of the ability to cause the latter (through cloud seeding), though is the first claim - that to *move* clouds - even possible in real life through artificial means?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How it's done in the series or how it's done in real life?

Comment: I'm going to guess magic, since after all these are flying horses.

Answer (score 7):

The clouds in *My Little Pony: Friendship in Magic* are **cartoon clouds**, so everything you know about how clouds work and react in the so called *real* life is unsuitable. The wind induced by their wings suffice to do the job.